# How to create an Array from grabbing objects values from an API

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, data-structures

[image]

Hello, I am trying to create an array of the data for height from an api as 
**[270, 1440, 1440, 1440, 1440]**  but am having trouble understanding how the process work.

I have tried using

```
var result = screenshots.map((ele) => ele.height)
```

, but I know you got to incorporate a key value like

```
screenshots.map((ele,key) => ele.height)
```

somehow.

Comment: Can you post the expected output?

Comment: What is wrong with `var result = screenshots.map((ele) => ele.height)` ?

Comment: I am trying to create an array  for height as height =  [270, 1440, 1440, 1440, 1440]. I try var result = screenshots.map((ele) => ele.height) but keep getting value undefined.

Comment: what is the variable name storing your data? (eg: you may need to do `data.screenshots.map(...)`)

Comment: how you are getting the screenshots array object

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly sure what your asking, but you can read up on how to use map [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

There is no "key" parameter, only: currentValue, index, and array.

Your example of how to create a "result" array for heights should work.

If you're trying to create an array of objects with a reduced set of keys, you could do something like this:

```
const result = screenshots.map(ele => ({
  height: ele.height,
  imageId: ele.image_id
}));
```

If you provided more clarify with regard to what you're asking, someone might be able to help you better.

Comment: By `key`, I think OP means the `index`